# How to get a model for a non-released spaCy version (v3)?

Tags: spacy

I want to try out the develop branch of [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) in order to test the features of v3. I built it successfully, but get the following message when trying to download a model:

'No compatible models found for v3.0.0 of spaCy'

What can I do? How are contributors supposed to get models for a non-released version?

This is the Dockerfile I used:

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    make \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN git clone https://github.com/explosion/spaCy /spaCy 
WORKDIR /spaCy
RUN git checkout develop
ENV PYTHONPATH=.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python setup.py build_ext --inplace
RUN python setup.py install

RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```